# Многокритериальный анализ текста с помощью нейронной сети

Tags: алгоритм, нейронные-сети

В общем у меня имеется некоторая задача, цели - учебные.

Имеется, допустим, большая база вакансий, которые можно использовать для обучения сети. Имеется список вакансий в виде обычного текста, или, как например на хедхантере список ключевых навыков, место работы, требуемый опыт, а также не особо длинный текст с описанием требований и место физического расположения работы. Имеются также данные потенциального работника, которые он уже в любой нужной форме может преподнести. Например его области знаний, желаемая зарплата, место жительства.

Необходимо из некоторых заново полученных вакансий отобрать кандидату с его данными самые подходящие. Обязательным требованием является так или иначе использовать нейронную сеть, приветствуется сверточная, но не обязательно, хотя из того, что я читал, говорят, что для задач подобного рода можно использовать и более простые вещи вроде байеса, деревьев и т.д. И собственно я только начал разбираться в нейронных сетях, хотел бы попросить советы.

Насколько мне пока-что позволяют мои знания, я вижу это так: надо сначала подготовить датасет для обучения, обычные тексты всегда сначала определенным образом нормировать, разделить еще предварительно на части, которые очень часто обособлены друг от друга, подготовить список областей, для каждой из которых в процентом отношении сетью либо последовательностью математических моделей будет выводиться, с какой вероятностью упоминается данная область, и также процентные оценки потенциальной сложности работы, ответственности, и чего-нибудь еще. Затем с некоторым процентным порогом отбираются вакансии, подходящие под навыки кандидата, и в финале каким-либо методом многокритериальной оптимизации, например иерархий, отбираются вакансии лучшие по важности запрашиваемых кандидатом критериев (ключевых навыков), физическому расположению, зарплате.

Может есть более лучшие способы все это сделать, особенно, что именно на выходе можно реализовать нейронной сети, какую именно нейронную сеть тут можно использовать, или можно использовать несколько разных нейронных сетей со своими задачами?

Мне надо хотя бы составить именно работоспособный четкий алгоритм, способный как-то решать эту задачу, по шагам, можно сказать блок-схему, показывающую последовательность применения конкретных математических моделей. Это я должен сделать достаточно срочно, но по этому алгоритму уже потом, на что у меня будет гораздо больше времени, несколько месяцев, я буду реализовывать все, разбираясь подробно, так как сейчас я не знаю, на чем именно надо сконцентрироваться.

Comment: На данном рессурсе принят такой алгоритм работы. Вы описываете проблему, приводите свой вариант ее решения, показываете, что именно у вас не получается -  вам помогают в решении конкретной проблемы или отвечают на конкретно заданный вопрос. А пока у вас предложение "составить работоспособный четкий алгоритм, способный решать задачу, по шагам, блок-схему. И сделать это достаточно срочно".  Т.е. сделать это за вас. С такими предложениями лучше на фриланс биржу.

Comment: Я не прошу сделать за меня всю работу и реализацию. Меня интересует, какие инструменты я мог бы рассмотреть. В 3 абзаце я описал, как вижу работу алгоритма. А самое главное, что мне хотелось узнать, можно ли вписать в эту схему одну или несколько нейросетей на упомянутое или может другое какое-либо место, и какой вид нейросетей под эту задачу лучше всего может подойдет, что обучение ее на разбор текста в нужном ключе будет эффективным, является ли удачным на выходе сети использовать вероятность присутствия определенных критериев. Чисто с идеологической точки зрения, чтобы я знал что изучить.

Comment: python-библиотека sklearn